# Javascript or Typescript Based windows application

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, windows

Is there any option to develop Windows application using Javascript and Typescript and Nodejs. Give me some suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any option to develop Windows application using Javascript and Typescript and Nodejs

Quite a few.

## Personal thoughts

The most hot right now is Electron https://electronjs.org/

Comment: Thanks Basarat.. Will it support for MAC..?

Comment: Yes electron does

Answer (score 1):

**Options to develop Windows application using Javascript and Typescript**

1. Cordova with Angular 2/4/5. (Some limitations wrt plugins and angular material designs).
2. As basarat mentioned, Electron has a good support for creating desktop applications.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an older question on SO, I recommend using Tauri to build a Windows application with TypeScript. Tauri is lighter and more optimized than Electron. The size of the application could be reduced by 90% in my work.
Please refer to the project release before and after version of 0.0.14: https://github.com/yetone/openai-translator/releases